# Get all associated value of a attributes in all products of category

Tags: magento-1.9

i have category tree and product association like this

```
-> Parent category
  -> Sub Category1(Product1 and Product2 associated with this category)
  -> Sub Category2(Product3 and Product4 ''     ''   ''   ''   ''     )
  -> Sub Category3(Product4 and Product5 ''     ''   ''   ''   ''     )
```

And i have an attribute `manufacturer` with options `brand A`,`brand B`, `brand C`, `brand D` and `brand E`

The five products have attribute `manufacturer` values assigned to them.

Now, all i have is `Parent category id` *(id=5)* and i want to get which of the attribute values are associated with all the products under it ?

**What i tried is this**

```
<?php 
    //with parent category id getting subcategories
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
            $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
            $subcategories->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','url'));
            $manufacturers = array();
            if (count($subcategories) > 0){
                foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
                    array_push($subcatIds, $subcategory->getId());

                    $catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcategory->getId()); 
                    //getting all products collection to get attribute value
                    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
                    $collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model);
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
                    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('manufacturer'));
                    $collection->addStoreFilter();  

                    //and finally getting unique attribute value 
                    if(!empty($collection)){
                            foreach ($collection as $_product):
                                if(!in_array($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'), $manufacturers)){
                                    array_push($manufacturers, $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
                                }
                            endforeach;

                    }
                }
            }
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($manufacturers); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I'm being able to get the result, but this is taking much time to load. As i'm getting this for megamenu.*(In mega menu with categories, i want to present brands associated with the category)* Is there any other options to do this ?

Drawback : This time i have only 65 products on those subcategories, and with the increase in number of products on those subcategories, the loading time will increase.